# .net core dependecy injection 'IMyService' is a type which is not valid in a given context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm using ASP.NET CORE WEB API trying to use my service in my controller.

So I injected service in a controller by using DI.

But unfortunatelly when I registered it in `Startup.cs` I'm getting error `IMyService' is a type which is not valid in a given context`.

Here's my code:

```
namespace MyDemoApp.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped(IProductService, ProductService);
        }
    }
}
```

`ProductService` is in another project in class library:

```
namespace MyDemoApp.Services
{
    public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _HttpClient;

        public ProductService(HttpClient HttpClient)
        {
            _HttpClient = HttpClient;
        }
        public async Task<string> RequestProductUrlFromAnotherAPI(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var prodUrl = "https://......";
            var response = await _HttpClient.Get<ProductDto>(prodUrl, cancellationToken);
             
            if(response!= null && response.Success && response.Data != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.Data))
            {
                return response.Data;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Data is not retrieved.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IProductService), typeof(ProductService));
```

or better:

```
services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
```

First one is [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddScoped_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Type_System_Type_) accepting two instances of `System.Type` class, [`typeof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) operator obtains the `System.Type` instance for a type name.

Second one is [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddScoped__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_) having two [generic type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) (also see [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)).

Comment: thanks man!  I used ( ) instead of < >

Comment: @Roxy'Pro was glad to help!